# Relation query undefined method

Tags: php, laravel-5

In my setting model class i have this

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
```

and in my user model class i have this

```
 public function settings()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\settings', 'id');
    }
```

I tried both these queries, trying to get the user information but failed.

```
$data = DB::table('settings')
                        ->where('id', '=', $id)
                        ->get()
                        ->toArray();
```

and

```
$table = \App\settings::where('id', '=', $id);
        $query = $table->user()
                       ->get()
                       ->toArray();
```

I'm getting this error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::user()
```

How do you do relation query? Sorry new to laravel here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$table = \App\settings::where('id', '=', $id)->first();
$query = $table->user->toArray();
```

Eager load

```
$table = \App\settings::with('user')->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
$query = $table->user->toArray();
```

Comment: on the 1st query, i when i `dd($query)` i get `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::user does not exist.`

on the 2nd i get `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.settings_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`settings_id` in (1, 3, 4, 5, 6))`

Comment: oop, first query edited: $table = \App\settings::where('id', $id)->first();
can you show column of table user and settings ?
In laravel document: $this->hasMany('App\User', 'foreign_key_on_settings_table', 'local_key_on_settings_table');